# ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT Wordpress website hosted on GCP

Tags: wordpress, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, bitnami

I'm new to GCP and using Bitnami I installed wordpress on GCP and redirected my domain to GCP. As I don't know much about cloud computing it worked and was working fine until a few days ago when anyone opens the website it takes some time to load and after that it shows:

> ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

I tried searching online but it's a common error and there is a lot of other information but nothing in regards to GCP. Now I don't know what to check in GCP to see if it's working but here is a screenshot of Compute Engine for the website:

[Screenshot of Compute Engine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WhKjz.png)

And the Cloud Platform Status seems to be fine too:

[Screenshot of Cloud Platform Status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/amzAT.png)

Comment if you need more info as I can't seems to figure out what to share here so that the thing causing this error can be identified.

Comment: what size instance did you install it on

Comment: The error `ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT` means nobody is listening. Did the public (external) IP address for the instance change? Is the IP address static or ephemeral? Most likely you have an ephemeral IP address. Solution: change the IP address to be static (fixed).

Comment: Bitnami Engineer here. If you changed the IP of your instance, you will need to change your DNS records to use that new one. Regarding the default Apache's page, it seems you installed the apache system's package and that's why you see that page. You will need to stop and remove that service (`sudo service apache2 stop && sudo service apache2 disable`) and start the Bitnami's one again (`sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh start`)

Comment: Now you know the original problem (IP address change). You solved that from happening again by making the address static. Now you need to update the DNS resource records in your DNS server to use the new IP address. Once this change is complete, it can take a day or so for the world to refresh their DNS cache. Also, reboot the server now so that all the services re-initialize plus review @JotaMartos suggestions.

Comment: @JotaMartos you solution worked like magic :D it's working now Thank You so much.

Comment: Glad to hear that. I just posted the same message as answer of the topic so the users can find the solution easier. It'd be great if you click on "This answer is useful". Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bitnami Engineer here. If the IP of your instance changed, you will need to change your DNS records to use that new one.

Regarding the default Apache's page, it seems you installed the apache system's package and that's why you see that page. You will need to stop and remove that service

```
sudo service apache2 stop && sudo service apache2 disable
```

and start the Bitnami's one again

```
sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh start
```